# 2 hard drives / HD1: UBuntu HD2: Win7. best practice isolated os's for dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, bios

is there any reason this wouldn't work or is a bad idea?  in bios make the HD1 the default boot drive and installing ubuntu, and HD2 installing windows 7.  Then if i prefer to boot into windows i just go into my bios and change the boot order to start with drive 2?  I would rather not install both OS's on same drive or use vmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up GRUB to boot into the Windows OS. Just install Windows 7 first on your first disk, install Ubuntu on the second and configure the BIOS to boot the second disk. The installer will take care of detecting your Win7 disk.